# Object Oriented Programming issue with lists

Tags: c#, object-oriented-analysis

I have two classes `GenericNameValue` and `SpecificNameValue` with inherits from `GenericNameValue`.

I have a function that takes the parameter `List<GenericNameValue>`. I would like to be able to pass in `List<SpecificNameValue>`. The function does nothing with the special properties of the `SpecificNameValue`.

What is the best method to do this?

```
public class GenericNameValue
{
    public string FieldName{get;set;}
    public string FieldValue{get;set;}
}

public class SpecificNameValue : GenericNameValue
{
    public string SpecificFieldValue{ get; set; }
}

public static UtitlityClass
{
    public string CombineAllFields(List<GenericNameValue> mylist)
    {
        //.... do stuff with each item
    }
}

//......Example of calling the utilityclass
string stuff = UtilityClass.CombineAllFields(mySpecificNameValue);
```

So is there a specific syntax I am missing?  Should I be using something different like Abstracts?

Sorry this is just one of those things that has caused me headaches for a while and would like an elegant solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you expect to get `mySpecificNameValue`?  Is it unclear of what it is.

Comment: mySpecificNameValue is a list of SpecificNameValues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<T>` is not covariant, your method will work with just an `IEnumerable<>` :

```
  public string CombineAllFields(IEnumerable<GenericNameValue> mylist)
  {
      .... do stuff with each item
  }
```

The full definitions from the library:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T> { }
public interface IList<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }
public interface IEnumerable<out T> { }
```

Note that your down-cast can only work with an interface that uses that `out` modifier.

Consider that using either a `List<T>` or an `IList<T>` parameter would allow your method to change the List. Deletions wouldn't matter but we have to prevent adding a `GenericNameValue` to a `List<SpecificNameValue>`. `IEnumerable<>` won't let you add to a collection so covariance is safe.

Comment: @Khan It works because `IEnumerable` is covariant. It can work with derived types

Comment: It would work fine with the answer provided because, as Henk mentioned, IEnumerables are covariant. It allows you to supply a more derived type in place of the base type.

Comment: @Khan - no, that expression is convertible to `IEnumerable<>`, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Seeing is believing, thats awesome.

Answer (score 1):

*Henk Holterman*'s answer is definitely the way to go.

If you're set on using a `List<T>` or you're in *.NET 2.0* or *3.0*, you have the option of using a generic parameter with a constraint:

```
public static string CombineAllFields<T>(List<T> mylist) where T : GenericNameValue
{
    //.... do stuff with each item
}
```